# CSS3 - Transition effect slide background position

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am having a transition effect that does a slide down/up on hover. Of course it makes sense, but I want it to fade in/out slowly like border bottom.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(6, 7, 11);
}
.bar-logout {
  float: left;
  background: rgb(7, 8, 13);
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(112, 101, 58);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.bar-logout span {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
}
.bar-logout span span.logout {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(164, 157, 139);
  padding-top: 9px;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.bar-logout span span.logout .logout-icon {
  float: left;position:relative;bottom:2px;background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/eCXybOC.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:0 -16px;margin:0 8px 0 0;width:16px;height:16px;-webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out; }
  .bar-logout: hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(200, 180, 85);
  }
  .bar-logout:hover > span span.logout .logout-icon {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="bar-logout">
  <span>
    <span class="logout"><div class="logout-icon"></div>LOGOUT</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: sta zelis da postignes ?

Comment: You prefer only fade in and out and no sliding?..

Comment: Marko Mackic pa ova ikona za logout da ne radi slide neko kao fade out/in, bas isto kao ovaj border bottom..
@repzero Yes, like this bottom border.

Comment: Do you mean a simple fade-in affect [like this example](http://jsbin.com/tihuliwupo/edit?html,css,output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to achieve the fade-in/out effect (that you are trying to create) using a single element when the background images are part of a sprite. This is because the sprite will always need a slide movement. For the slide movement to be invisible and fade to happen, we need more than one state change - (1) fade-out the current image (`opacity: 0`), (2) change the `background-position` to the correct position (3) fade-in the image (`opacity: 1`). Since it requires more than opacity change, it cannot be achieved with transitions on one element. (**Note:** It can be done with animations though).

When we use 2 elements (one of which is a pseudo-element), we can achieve the effect that you are looking for.  I am not quite sure what is the type of effect that you are looking for (because the border's change is not exactly a fade-in/out, it is just a color change) and so I am giving two samples with two different effects. You can choose **whichever of these two effects suit your needs**.

**Effect similar to the one on the border bottom:** (that is, the icon looks like it is changing color)

This is done by adding a gray colored icon on top of the yellow colored icon (using a pseudo-element) and then changing its `opacity` to 0 on hover. The opacity change means that the yellow colored icon at the bottom comes into view when the hover is on.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(6, 7, 11);
}
.bar-logout {
  float: left;
  background: rgb(7, 8, 13);
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(112, 101, 58);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.bar-logout span {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
}
.bar-logout span span.logout {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(164, 157, 139);
  padding-top: 9px;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.bar-logout span span.logout .logout-icon {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/eCXybOC.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.bar-logout span span.logout .logout-icon:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/eCXybOC.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 -16px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
}
.bar-logout:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(200, 180, 85);
}
.bar-logout:hover > span span.logout .logout-icon:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar-logout">
  <span>
<span class="logout"><div class="logout-icon"></div>LOGOUT</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

---

**Actual fade-in/out effect:** (that is gray icon fades out, yellow fades-in on hover and vice-versa)

This is again done by adding the gray colored icon on top of the yellow icon (using a pseudo-element) and on hover, the gray icon's `opacity` is changed to 0 at first and then after a delay the yellow icon's `opacity` is changed to 1 (this is achieved using `transition-delay` equal to `transition-duration`).

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(6, 7, 11);
}
.bar-logout {
  float: left;
  background: rgb(7, 8, 13);
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(112, 101, 58);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.bar-logout span {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
}
.bar-logout span span.logout {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(164, 157, 139);
  padding-top: 9px;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.bar-logout span span.logout .logout-icon {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/eCXybOC.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.bar-logout span span.logout:before {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 8px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/eCXybOC.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 -16px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.bar-logout:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(200, 180, 85);
}
.bar-logout:hover > span span.logout:before {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.bar-logout:hover > span span.logout .logout-icon{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar-logout">
  <span>
    <span class="logout"><div class="logout-icon"></div>LOGOUT</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Based on your comment

**Here is a snippet**

```css
body { background-color:rgb(6,7,11); }
.bar-logout { float:left;background:rgb(7,8,13);width:auto;height:40px;border-bottom:1px solid rgb(112,101,58);cursor:pointer;-webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out; }
.bar-logout span { float:right;padding:6px 10px 6px 10px; }
.bar-logout span span.logout { font-family:"Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:rgb(164,157,139);padding-top:9px;text-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgb(0,0,0);-webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out; }
.bar-logout span span.logout .logout-icon { float:left;position:relative;bottom:2px;background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/eCXybOC.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:0 -16px;margin:0 8px 0 0;width:16px;height:16px;-webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;opacity:0; }
.bar-logout:hover { border-bottom:1px solid rgb(200,180,85); }
.bar-logout:hover > span span.logout .logout-icon { opacity:1 }
```

```html
<div class="bar-logout">
<span>
<span class="logout"><div class="logout-icon"></div>LOGOUT</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont want it like that, you didnt understand me..I want the icon change background position but withoud slide in transition, but fade in/out..these 2 icons are in the same image and i change it with background position..

Comment: Answer edited....no transition for background slidding just background position change quickly and fade in effect as you wanted (The result is actually the same)

Comment: i want this icon http://i.imgur.com/6kFCOTp.png to make transition effect on this http://i.imgur.com/FzK3wUG.png But i make those two icons in one image so when i hover i do background position to change icon..But when i do it with transition it slide down/up, not like bottom border..

I can't speak very well English, so its hard to explain what i really want..

Comment: check this link and see if it is this you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/rLkvL2oc/ (ensure you click run and hover over image)